How do I create a graphic representing the changing votes in an Ranked Choice Voting Election in Python?
I have the below code to run a ranked choice election and it works but I want to graph the changes in votes each round. I can make them manually in excel and paint but I haven't figured out how to get the numbers right in a matplotlib graph.
Here's what I want to generate, basically 4 images for each round. The first graph is the initial ballot count, second graph highlights the losing candidate, third graph shows how those votes will now be split up, fourth graph shows where those votes will be going, fifth graph shows the next round and who will be eliminated.
Image of five graphs showing how each voting round went:

import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation


# Function to read ballots from a CSV file
def read_ballots(csv_file):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    ballots = []
    candidates = Counter()

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        ballot = []
        for choice in row[0:]:
            if not pd.isna(choice):
                ballot.append(choice)
                candidates[choice] += 1
        ballots.append(ballot)

    threshold = len(ballots)/2
    print('Eliminating non-viable candidates')
    for candidate, count in candidates.items():
        if count < threshold:
            ballots = eliminate_candidate(ballots, candidate)

    return ballots


# Function to count votes
def count_votes(ballots):
    first_choice_counts = Counter()
    for ballot in ballots:
        if ballot:
            first_choice_counts[ballot[0]] += 1
    return first_choice_counts


# Function to eliminate the candidate with the fewest votes
def eliminate_candidate(ballots, candidate_to_eliminate):
    print(f"Eliminating {candidate_to_eliminate}")
    for ballot in ballots:
        if candidate_to_eliminate in ballot:
            ballot.remove(candidate_to_eliminate)
    return ballots


# Function to run the ranked choice voting process
def ranked_choice_voting(csv_file):
    ballots = read_ballots(csv_file)
    total_votes = len(ballots)
    print(f"Total ballots: {total_votes}")

    round_number = 1

    nested_dict = lambda: defaultdict(nested_dict)
    rounds = nested_dict()
    while True:
        print(f"\nRound {round_number} results:")
        vote_counts = count_votes(ballots)
        for candidate, count in vote_counts.items():
            print(f"{candidate}: {count} votes")

        # save current round counts
        for ballot in ballots:
            if len(ballot) == 0:
                if rounds[round_number]["Exhausted Ballots"]["Exhausted Ballots"]:
                 rounds[round_number]["Exhausted Ballots"]["Exhausted Ballots"] += 1
                else:
                    rounds[round_number]["Exhausted Ballots"]["Exhausted Ballots"] = 1

            if len(ballot) > 0:
                if rounds[round_number][ballot[0]][ballot[0]]:
                    rounds[round_number][ballot[0]][ballot[0]] += 1
                else:
                    rounds[round_number][ballot[0]][ballot[0]] = 1

            if len(ballot) > 1:

                if rounds[round_number][ballot[0]][ballot[1]]:
                    rounds[round_number][ballot[0]][ballot[1]] += 1
                else:
                    rounds[round_number][ballot[0]][ballot[1]] = 1

        # Check for a winner
        for candidate, count in vote_counts.items():
            if count > total_votes / 2:
                print(f"\nWinner: {candidate} with {count} votes")
                return candidate, rounds



        # Eliminate candidate with the fewest votes
        candidate_to_eliminate = min(vote_counts, key=vote_counts.get)
        ballots = eliminate_candidate(ballots, candidate_to_eliminate)
        round_number += 1


def rounds_to_bar_chart(rounds):
    for round_num in rounds:
        round_for_bar_graph = defaultdict(dict)
        minvalue = min(rounds[round_num][key][key] for key in list(rounds[round_num].keys())[:-1])
        minkeys = [key for key in rounds[round_num] if rounds[round_num][key][key] == minvalue]
        keepkeys = [key for key in list(rounds[round_num].keys())[:-1] if key not in minkeys]
        numberofframes = 0
        for key in keepkeys:
            round_for_bar_graph[key][key] = rounds[round_num][key][key]
            for minkey in minkeys:
                round_for_bar_graph[key][minkey] = rounds[round_num][minkey][key]
                numberofframes = max(numberofframes, rounds[round_num][minkey][key])

        for i in range(round(numberofframes/10)):
            for key in keepkeys:
                for minkey in minkeys:
                    if round_for_bar_graph[key][minkey] > 0:
                        try:
                            round_for_bar_graph[minkey][key] += 10
                        except:
                            round_for_bar_graph[minkey][key] = 10

                        round_for_bar_graph[key][minkey] = max(0, round_for_bar_graph[key][minkey] - 10)

            df = pd.DataFrame(round_for_bar_graph)
            df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
            plt.show()







# Example usage
csv_file = 'rcv.csv'
winner, rounds = ranked_choice_voting(csv_file)

rounds_to_bar_chart(rounds)

I've added code to keep track of the rounds and "animate" the graphs. How do I keep track of the graphs and save them as an animation with matplotlib? Is there any better way to iterate through the dictionaries?
Is there a better way to do this:
    if rounds[round_number]["Exhausted Ballots"]["Exhausted Ballots"]:
      rounds[round_number]["Exhausted Ballots"]["Exhausted Ballots"] += 1
    else:
      rounds[round_number]["Exhausted Ballots"]["Exhausted Ballots"] = 1

Just to clarify, in rounds_to_bar_chart(rounds), the rounds dictionary looks like this:




candidate 1
candidate 2
candidate 3
candidate 4




candidate 1
rank 1 votes for candidate 1
rank 2 votes for candidate 2
rank 2 votes for candidate 3
rank 2 votes for candidate 4


candidate 2
rank 2 votes for candidate 1
rank 1 votes for candidate 2
rank 2 votes for candidate 3
rank 2 votes for candidate 4


candidate 3
rank 2 votes for candidate 1
rank 2 votes for candidate 2
rank 1 votes for candidate 3
rank 2 votes for candidate 4


candidate 4
rank 2 votes for candidate 1
rank 2 votes for candidate 2
rank 2 votes for candidate 3
rank 1 votes for candidate 4



and I'm transforming it to




candidate 1
candidate 2
candidate 3
candidate 4 (loser)




candidate 1
rank 1 votes for candidate 1
0
0
0


candidate 2
0
rank 1 votes for candidate 2
0
0


candidate 3
0
0
rank 1 votes for candidate 3
0


candidate 4 (loser)
rank 2 votes for candidate 1 [Cell A]
rank 2 votes for candidate 2 [Cell B]
rank 2 votes for candidate 3 [Cell C]
0



Which I then want to animate so it shows the following:




candidate 1
candidate 2
candidate 3
candidate 4 (loser)




candidate 1
rank 1 votes for candidate 1
0
0
n -> [Cell A]


candidate 2
0
rank 1 votes for candidate 2
0
n -> [Cell B]


candidate 3
0
0
rank 1 votes for candidate 3
n -> [Cell C]


candidate 4 (loser)
[Cell A] -n -> 0
[Cell B] -n -> 0
[Cell C] -n -> 0
0



The graphs end up going from this to this

Welcome to [so]. Since this site is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand where you are specifically having trouble. Please see: Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?  for more details.  Then edit your question to clarify with what aspect of your problem you require our help.

It is really difficult to provide assistance, without sufficient sample data.  For example, without knowing either the format of your vote data and a sample of the data or how the rounds table reflects the information shown in your images, it is not possible to provide any guidance.  In addition, it is unclear if you desire just a final graphic or intermediary graphics showing vote transformation.  Finally, there is no explanation of what the transformation rules happen to be.
